# Pitch-Accent languages like Ancient Greek sometimes acquire a dynamic component. Any papers on this change?

Tags: accent, pitch-accent

This is kind of the opposite of *tonogenesis*. All languages with stress use a combination of pitch, force and duration to represent a stressed syllable. Some use only (or primarily) pitch.

What sources or papers deal with the introduction of force to a previously pitch-only accent? It occurs in the transition from Attic to Koine' Greek, and several other periods and languages. But has anyone got ideas on what causes this prosodic shift?

Comment: Can you point to any scientific publication that shows the existence of a language where stress uses only pitch? That would be a major discovery. I'm aware of mistaken beliefs on that point, but no actual evidence that such a thing exists.

Comment: I don't think this is particularly controversial. Plenty of languages have been presumed or shown to use primarily pitch for a syllable accent, and even those that don't, like English, have a pitch component. But see for example (regarding Ancient Greek and Vedic Sanskrit:) pp 230ff
Allen, W. S. (1973). Accent and Rhythm. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

Comment: See also the question (and answer by TKR) http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8847/are-there-languages-in-which-lexical-pitch-accent-and-phonemic-vowel-length-vary?rq=1

Comment: Allen just *presumes*. I'm looking for experimental evidence, Something to go with the numerous phonetic studies by Ladefoged, Ohala, Hombert and everyone subsequently.

Comment: "presumed or shown"???  Puts me in mind of a great Beckett quote that goes something like "I would never do such a thing unless it were absolutely necessary or convenient to do so."